# Do we use hash tables in practise?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures

I just read about Hash tables and am curious if we use it in practise because if I write a program that stores data in a Hash table, the storage will only be temporary. So, why not use a database to store it ?

In other words, what kinds of real world programs use hash tables for their functioning?

Comment: Lots of programs use hash tables!  Whats wrong with an in-memory collection.  In memory collections are one of the most important building blocks of any program.

Comment: Try imagining how the data would be stored inside the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use hash tables to store data while you are working. Using the database for that would in many cases be orders of magnitude slower then using in-memory hash tables. See for example:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caching

Hash maps are about speed, not persistence.

Take a look at the other uses in the `Uses` section of `Hash table` entry on Wikipedia:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 1):

There is such a thing as an on-disk hash table, e.g. [Tokyo Cabinet's hash database](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html#tchdbapi).

Answer (score 0):

hash table is for fast access, let's say that you need to search a lot of records, that will be very expensive.  Using a hash function will take you almost directly to the portion you want to search.  And you may implement a data base schema hash table alike, so they are not necessarily temporary storage.